# How can I prevent two applications clashing, because they use one database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, nhibernate, architecture

### Situation

There are two applications:

- Windows Service

  - Processes queue messages
  - Performs a lot of database I/O (SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT)
- ASP.NET Application

  - Primarily uses database for SELECT queries

Both applications make use of one (mirrored) MSSQL database (SQL Server 2014). We query data using NHibernate ORM. Both applications and the database server have it's own dedicated server.

### Problem

There are millions of records in the database, so query's only work if there are sufficient indexes available. The Windows Service mostly uses Clustered indexes for queries, but there are a lot of Non-clustered indexes for querying other fields in the web application. The Windows service should be as fast as possible.

- These non-clustered indexes make update and insert queries slower.
- Use of the web application has a large impact on service performance.

### Our solutions thus far

- Scale server up
- Archive data
- Improve indexes

## Question

**Are there other solutions, besides our current efforts?** We don't want to add extra servers, we want to solve this issue using new architecture or software. In an ideal world, use of the web application would not affect performance of the Windows Service at all.

Comment: Is your problem asp.net queries blocking the service or something else? Looking into plan cache for most expensive queries and wait stats might be a good idea.

Comment: My bottleneck is hdd io (database). I would love it, if there was a way to not use the database from the web application while still having recent data (no more than a few minutes behind).

Comment: Are the asp.net queries reading everything from disc, if the actual disc I/O is the problem with read only queries? Could more memory help to keep everything in cache (buffer pool)?

Comment: If the problem is not enough memory, Page Life Expectancy might reveal it, for example using: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/13/sql-server-what-is-page-life-expectancy-ple-counter/

Comment: @JamesZ some tables contain over 100.000.000 records, so I don't think throwing memory at it will help. Besides: There is 512GB of memory available. I will look into Page Life Expectancy and see if it will help my case, thank you.

Comment: Looking at queries with most logical reads from plan cache might help too if you haven't done that. Sometimes it's a surprise how much something can actually read if there's for example varchar vs nvarchar problem in search criteria or non-optimal index / plan in use.

Answer (score 2):

Not an ideal world.  Any activity on a table is going to effect other activity.

As you know indexes slow down insert, update, and delete.

Index maintenance will help (defrag)

Fill factor less than 100 will help (like 50)

Try and perform insert in the order of the PK
If not the PK in the order of as many indexes as possible

Do set base update, insert, and delete when possible
Way more efficient to get one write lock and 1000 inserts than one at a time

The primary impact of the Web Application is that is takes locks.
Do you have the option of select .... with (nolock)?
With (nolock) is dirty read so only use with caution.

Comment: I'll do some research on dirty reads (nolock) and see if it will help my case, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what version of SQL Server you are on, nor did you describe your HDD scenario (shared storage, local storage, etc.), but you did say HDD was the bottleneck (not memory, correct?), but didn't say if it was due to writes, or writes + reads.   However, since you have a requirement of being only a couple minutes behind, and you do not want to introduce a reporting server - If you are on SQL 2012, you could use AlwaysOn with Async Replica, just ensure the secondary replica is on a different set of disks than the Primary db. By separating the secondary db, the reads will not conflict with the writes, while still being only seconds behind the primary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Blam's suggestions, you may want to look into caching reads for your ASP.NET application, probably using ASP.NET's cache class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff477235%28v=vs.100%29.aspx as well for an implementation sample.

If you can tolerate dirty reads (which may or may not be the case - would it be ok for the application user to see partially updated data?), you could combine this with `SELECT ... WITH(NOLOCK)`.

The basic idea would be that your database will only get hit by the WebApplication every 5 minutes or so (but for a larger read) instead of in real time.  The question here would become how much data you have to cache every 5 minutes.  If you can cache a significant portion of the data that gets used by your users in a reasonably sized cache, great.  There are a few strategies you could take here:

- Cache only data that doesn't change that often, and update that cache less frequently
- Cache only data related to an object/entity that has been recently updated
- Cache only data that is frequently requested by the site

All of these would require some analysis of when and how your ASP application is hitting the DB.

You could combine this with a polling pattern as well for further improvements, i.e. when the Service updates an entity in the database, it also creates a record in another table that your ASP.NET application is polling to keep the cache up to date.  The polling table would contain a master key (or set of keys) to access the entity, so your ASP cache updater could request only those entities that are out of date.

Comment: Just as a warning, nolock can also (rarely) cause you either read same row twice or miss a row completely -- and if the problem is not blocking, nolock probably doesn't help

Comment: He's almost definitely got blocking issues, as he has a service that's frequently writing to the table and a website that's frequently reading from it.  But yes, NOLOCK should be used with caution.

Comment: That was my first guess too, and checking index usage / query plans for the blocking queries should also be done -- it might be a lot simpler and cheaper than trying to solve it otherwise.

Comment: I will look into your answer more thorough later today, but I think caching won't help much. Many queries are not performed very often (parameters differ much), but they do tend to have a large effect on the database. I think caching won't help much if most queries have different parameters?

Comment: @DanField my situation is exactly as how you describe it to be. My Service writes and updates a lot (+- two milion writes in 24 hours). My web application mostly reads. There aren't a lot of blocking issues and things are going pretty fast, but I think it could be faster if there was less load on my database. So basically: I want to know if there is technology (an extra layer?) available that could bring my web application's reads down to a minimum.

Comment: @annemartijn In the problem statement "Use of the web application has a large impact on service performance".   How do you explain that other than  blocking issues?